# Java JNI error has occured

Tags: java

When i try to run the jar it give me the next error.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and  try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: c com/jaunt/ResponseException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jaunt.ResponseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

What i have to do to get pass it?

Comment: If this is a jar you downloaded and are trying to run, this sort of error tends to occur when all dependencies that are required for the jar weren't included.

Comment: it is my program and i exported it from eclipse and then i try to run it from the terminal in linux

Comment: i also used jaunt as external library

Comment: Ah then that's the issue, the jar isn't being included with the build.  My understanding is you have to add it to the manifest file so it will be built with it.  I've always used Maven to do this for me, but [this oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) should help.

Comment: so it doesn't include it automatically?why?

Comment: No.  There might be some IDEs that do it automatically, but Java won't build libraries into your jar without a manifest file telling it to.  As to why, ask Oracle.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and your response.i found on stack another post to introduce external libraries and now it works

Comment: You're welcome, good luck.